# Bugged simultaneous edit

Tags: bug, edits, markdown-preview, diff

In the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19760375/revisions

A user made a minor edit to my post (edit 3) by correcting a mistake at the same time that I made a larger but non-conflicting edit to the post (edit 2).

A few unexpected things happened as a result:

- The post showed the state after my edit, without his edit applied, although it said he made the last edit (under the post).
- When I attempted to edit the post, the markup and preview showed a combination of both of our edits (my edit with his edit applied), but this differed from the actual visible post (my edit only).
- The diff in the revision history showed that his edit undid mine, which differed both from the displayed text and the markup/preview in subsequent edits.

To merge both of our edits I had to edit the post, make a temporary change, submit it, re-edit the post, undo the temporary change, and submit it. After that it seemed to be OK.

While I understand there are some current issues with simultaneous edits, there is a lot going on here. Essentially this edit left three different and conflicting versions of the post at various points on SO:

- Revision history showed latest version (if you work through the diffs) as his edit only (edit 3 undid edit 2).
- Visible post showed my edit only (edit 2).
- Markup/preview in editor showed merged version (edit 3 and edit 2 merged).

That's a big potential mess for posts with more complex formatting.

Comment: You must have misread; I described significantly more than a misattributed edit, none of which would be by design. (Also, it is impossible for two things to "overwrite each other".)

Comment: Scratch that. If you find this happening again, you should probably take some screenshots (unless this happens all the time to everyone). Why don't you think two things can overwrite each other?

Comment: Either user B's edit replaces user A's edit (the post should look as if user A never edited, although it will show up in the revision history) or user B gets notified of user A's edit and is prevented from committing his/her edit.

Comment: "Simultaneous edits overwrite each other" (I believe I said something like that) = "one edit overwrites the previous 'simultaneous' edit". Well, they're at least equal in my book.

Comment: I'm sure you got my point, now you're just arguing technicalities. Over and out.

Comment: This happened to me two days ago, and at first I thought I'd started an edit war over capitalizing W's in Wikipedia.